# Simulation results of MC34025 are different using same files for the LTspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, pwm, ltspice, converter

I made the converter circuit using MC34025 for the PWM signal. The computer, I used to design the circuit, works well. However, when I moved the file and ran it on another computer, the wrong waveform came out. I don't know why the wrong waveform came out.
[image: This is original result]
[image: This is the wrong result]
[image: MC34025 chip]
[image: Designed converter circuit]

Comment: Please edit your question to include your simulation settings and directives, the names of the measurements you were trying to graph (they're not visible from the screenshots), as well as a screenshot of your SPICE settings (Tools -> Control Panel -> SPICE) on both computers. You might also want to click View -> Spice Error Log after running a complete simulation to see if there's anything obviously wrong.

Comment: You probably have different settings: verify them in the Control Panel, the SPICE and Hacks! tabs. Or do a `diff` on the ini files (in `%APPDATA%`). If the versions are the same then the results should be identical. I presume the schematic has not been modified between runs and the readings are done between the same nodes (even if they are not labeled, becauase I can't read the waveforms you posted).